# How does laravel redirect first to public folder?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I am looking at a stock laravel 5.8 project and I am trying to understand how does Laravel redirect all the requests from the / to the /public folder.

There is no index.php file in the root and no .htaccess to redirect traffic to public?

Comment: It's not redirecting to the public folder. The **document root** is **set** to the **public** folder.

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I am using nginx and running on valet, which does it's own thing and does not care about any htaccess, so I guess that is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

laravel 5.8 i use the following

root .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```