# Laravel & VestaCP: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: laravel

Im trying to deploy a Laravel 5.8.* project to my host while using the next template: [Laravel web template for VestaCP](https://gist.github.com/peterbrinck/26684a078027a0c0c978a470be27edc3) but I am getting the next error:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at info@iberoseguridad.eu to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Also, this is the error log from my host:

```
[Mon Jun 03 19:17:12.497219 2019] [core:error] [pid 22984] [client 68.183.55.192:33376] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: mydomain
```

Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: check the .htaccess files in the root and the public

Comment: What should i look for?

Comment: Something that would cause a redirect loop, like a HTTP to HTTPS redirect that's misconfigured.

Comment: see if this helps, it's my answer to a previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384617/how-does-laravel-redirect-first-to-public-folder/56384716#56384716

Comment: I haven't modify anything on my `.htaccess` and my `public/.htaccess` looks exactly like the one in the solution provided. It keeps failing.